# Primary Key Sharepoint List

Tags: list, access

When creating a list in Sharepoint I cannot **edit** the **primary key name** and by default is named as **"ID"** for all my lists.

This is not helping me in the name identification in the rest of applications that use this data.

When I create a list in Access and export it to Sharepoint it is fine and keeps the name correctly, for example "ID_Customer".

I have many lists created by other users in Sharepoint and all keep the name "ID", and cannot change it.

Any help?

Regards,
Mikel.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the name of the ID column you can do it so:

- List Settings
- Select any column, say Created
- Edit the URL, replace Created with ID
- Now you can change ID to whatever you like

[Ref](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/11/how-to-rename-id-column-in-sharepoint.html)

Comment: Thanks!
Just in case it helps somebody, it was working with chrome and not with iexplorer (at least in my case). Thanks and regards!

Comment: @MasterPiece Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted in case it solved your issue!